# Angular 4 routing is not working

Tags: javascript, angular

Angular routing is not working.. here is the code

routs.ts: routing url definitions file.

```
import {BlankComponent} from "../layouts/blank.component";
export const routes=[
    {

    path:'',
    component:BlankComponent,
    children:[
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: 'home', loadChildren: '../pages/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule' }
    ]
},
{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }

]
```

routes.module.ts: routing module

```
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {RouterModule} from "@angular/router";
import { routes } from './routes';

@NgModule({
imports:[RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
exports:[RouterModule,]
})

export class RoutesModule{

constructor(){

}
}
```

Layout module:

```
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import {BlankComponent} from "./blank.component";
import {TopnavComponent} from "./topnav.component";

@NgModule({
declarations:[BlankComponent,TopnavComponent],
exports:[BlankComponent,TopnavComponent,RouterModule],
imports:[]
})
export class LayoutsModule{}
```

BlankComponent:

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";

@Component({

  selector:"sig-blank",
  templateUrl:'./blank.component.html'

})
export class BlankComponent{}
```

App module:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {LayoutsModule} from './layouts/layouts.module'
import {RoutesModule} from "./routes/routes.module"
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
     BrowserModule,
    LayoutsModule,
    RoutesModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

blank.component.html

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <section>

        <div class="container">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

app.component.html

```
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

This is the code i used in my project. but the routing is not working .
What is the wrong in my code. actually i have markup in my ./blank.component.html which i not included in the question. now the page displaying is the  content in app.component.html only

Comment: Perhaps you should elaborate on what "not working" means?

Comment: @cartant . Question edited.thnx

Comment: You're using nested routes. I'm sorry to say but I encountered a lot of issues implementing that. :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the component name at {path:'home',component:ComponentName,loadChildren: '../pages/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'}